# Front Door sidelite

Tags: doors

i need to replace my front door sidelite glass ( it is shattered)... It a designer/ privacy type glass with brass caming... The problem i am having is identifying the manufacture of the door ( its a door system, in that it has two sidelite's and a transom lite above as well& an oval design glass in the middle of the door) so i can contact the  manufacture to see if a replacement piece is available. Note:There is no markings etched on the glass.
Any help to identify would be appreciated.
 Thank you[image]

Comment: Open the door and look for a label along the edge, on the side with the hinges.

Answer (score 1):

Good luck.  Unless the door is fairly recent, it is unlikely that the replacement is still being made.  This is one of those fashion things.  It's trendy for a few years, then is passe.

Thoughts:

- Replace all three panels.  This allows you to maintain the similar looks, but opens the door to more providers.
- The existing setup illustration is insecure.  Break the sidelite nearest the latch, reach in, and unlock the door.  You may want to consider putting some form of resistant glazing.  This can be a sandwich with lexan as one layer, or mesh embedded in the glass.

Comment: It does look quite nice though...

Answer (score 0):

A stained glass repair person could repair this but expect it to be a bit expensive and take some time (they’d have to remove the entire side window so that they can work on it), and the match will likely not be perfect.

Or you can a stained glass workshop at your local community college and do it yourself. Warning, it’s very addictive.